How to configure routes when I have two WANs in one router with two NICs on Linux server?
I have one router with two WANs. 
The router has one LAN IP address: 192.168.0.1. 
I have a Linux server with two interfaces on the same subnet: eno1:192.168.0.2 eno2: 192.168.0.3.  On the router, I have DMZ from link 1 to 192.168.0.2 and DMZ from link 2 to 192.168.0.3.
I only get response from DMZ link 2 if I configure 192.168.0.3 on the eno1:1.
How can I configure these routes in Debian?

LINK1 → ROUTER DMZ1 (192.168.0.1) → 192.168.0.2 (eno1)
LINK2 → ROUTER DMZ2 (192.168.0.1) → 192.168.0.3 (eno2)

